# ValueError: freq too small

Tags: micropython, pwm, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to set up pwm in raspberry pi pico using micropython.
everything was ok until I set the frequency to 14,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9.
In these particular frequencies this error will raise:
ValueError: freq too small
this is my program:

```
from machine import Pin, PWM
led = PWM(Pin(25))
led.freq(14)
led.duty_u16(32512)
```

using different duty cycles and pins don't change the result.
I tried an older firmware and the latest firmware and there was no difference.

I tried circuitpython on the same board and it worked with no problem in the specified frequencies.

Do you know any solution or reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the allowed frequency for the Pico is 8Hz to 62.5MHz. So from your list of values (`14,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9`), both 9 and 14 should work fine.

Docs here: https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/rp2/quickref.html#pwm-pulse-width-modulation

Comment: Thank you. but same these frequencies have no problem in circuit python. and 9 and 14 are not working in micropython as i checked.